# Only retrieve records with at least one association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is pretty straightforward, but I guess I've never bumped into it before. I have a `Page` model that `hasMany Comment`. I'd like to pull all of the pages that have at least 1 comment, but eliminate pages with none. As I look at it, I realize that I'm not sure how to do that. I guess I could use ad hoc joins, but I'd rather use Containable, if that's possible. I've tried testing `not null` in the `Comment` conditions and one or 2 other things that were unlikely to work, but it seems like this should be possible.

What I get now, of course, is all pages and some of those page records have an empty `Comment` member. Be nice to skip passing around all of the extra cruft if I can do so.

My `find` call:

```
    $pages = $this->Folder->Page->find(
      'all',
      array(
        'contain' => array(
          'Comment' => array(
            'order' => array( 'Comment.modified DESC' ),
          ),
          'Folder' => array(
            'fields' => array( 'Folder.id' ),
          ),
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
          'Folder.group_id' => $id,
        ),
      )
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several approaches available other than ad-hoc joins:

1. Denormalize your dataset and add a has_comment flag to your pages table.  Add `'Page.has_comment' => 1` to your conditions.
2. Run your query against Comment, with DISTINCT page_id.

   ```
   $comments = $this->Folder->Page->Comment->find('all', array(
       'conditions' => array('DISTINCT Comment.page_id'
       'contain' => array(
           'Page' => array(
                   'Folder'
           )
       )
   );
   ```
3. First grab a distinct set of page ids from the comments table.

   ```
   $page_ids = $this->Folder->Page->Comment->find('list', array(
       'fields' => array('id', 'page_id'),
       'conditions' => array('DISTINCT Comment.page_id'),
   );
   $pages = $this->Folder->Page->find('all', array(
       'conditions' => array('Page.id' => $page_ids),
       'contain' => array(
           ...
       )
   );
   ```

Comment: Good suggestions, I'm going with option three.